# How to update the background image SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

how i can add an image or change the color for only one of my SP page?
at the moment the background color is white.

Regards

Comment: Well, for only one page (not site/web, right?) the fastest way would be custom CSS in a Content Editor Web Part.
Keep in mind, that copy/paste only will not help as SharePoint renders the given string as it is. You need to switch to Code View (or HTML View, I can't fully remember).

Comment: thanks for the response, its just one page that i need to change the color.

Comment: i am using the below code in content editor webpart however its not doing it<style>
body{
backgroundcolor:#FFA500;
}
</style> ​​​​​

Comment: You may have a typo in here. It should be called background-color. Reference: [w3cschool](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp).

Comment: oops, i have fixed my typo however the color didn't covered all the page.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this CSS on the page (Inside script editor or content editor)

```
<Style type="text/css">
#s4-workspace
{
   background-color: #ffffff
}
</style>
```